# 되 conjugated: 돼, 되어 both acceptable?

Tags: verb, conjugation

For verbs ending in 되다:

Can all such verbs conjugated as ~돼 for the infinitive form? And similarly can all such verbs also be conjugated as ~되어 for the infinitive form?

Does it depend on the verb as to which conjugated form is preferable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceptability or preference of "되어" vs "돼" does not depend on the verb, it is the same for both "되다" and any verb ending in "되다" (e.g. 선택되다). The same holds for e.g. "하여" vs "해". The contracted forms (돼, 해) are far more common in daily life, with the original forms' usage mostly being restricted to formal writing. I've never come across sentences such as "잘 되었어." or "나 내일 공부하여.", i.e. informal speech-style with the original forms, it almost looks jarring despite being grammatically valid.